# AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My app throw exception - "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content" in AlertDialog.

```
alertdialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
List<String> itemsIntoList = Arrays.asList(AlertDialogItems);
alertdialogbuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(AlertDialogItems, Selectedtruefalseenter code here, (dialog, which, isChecked) -> {});
alertdialogbuilder.setCancelable(false);

alertdialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("אישור", (dialog1, which) -> {
mMailNotification.setChecked(Selectedtruefalse[0]);
mMailAgree.setChecked(Selectedtruefalse[1]);
dialog1.dismiss();
});

AlertDialog dialog1 = alertdialogbuilder.create();

dialog1.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogTheme;
dialog1.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

dialog1.show();

ListView listView = dialog1.getListView();
listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY));
listView.setDividerHeight(2);
```

I think that "setLayoutDirection with RTL" is trouble maker but not sure - and it's have to be in rtl.

Answer (score 0):

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
  View view = new View(context);
  view.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
  builder.setView(view);
  builder.create();
```